# Exception Where it shouldn't be (System.FormatException). How to debug?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have never been so stumped in programming before. From what I have found this error is thrown when you try to convert a string into an int but why is it saying that the error is occurring on this line? There are no ints or strings to be seen.
[Please see this pic of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zU00.png)

How do I drill down to exactly where this conversion of string to int or whatever is happening?

Could this be a multithreading issue? I am a little new to C# multithreading. Can errors just be thrown from a different thread and show up on what is currently executing?

Other info that might help:

1. This error only happens about 20% of the time no matter what code I am changing around it.
2. There is a lot of work with comm ports. I feel like maybe some different-threaded code is working slow at one point and causing this error from a different place.
3. The likelihood of this error happening seems to jump up to 80% when the code hasn't been run for a while or the connected device is restarted.
4. This is the calling code:

   ```
   if (comPorts.Count > 0)
           {
               devices.AddRange(comPorts.Select(port =>
               {
                   var serialPort = new SerialPortAdapter(port, baudRate, Parity.None);
                   ICatsFtpSerialConnection catsFtpSerialConnection;
                   var fileManager = fileManagerFactory.GetFileManager(serialPort, baudRate, out catsFtpSerialConnection);
                   return new CatsDevice(port, fileManager, catsFtpSerialConnection, serialPort);
               }));
               Parallel.ForEach(devices, (device) =>
               {
                   device.GetFilesArray(new CancellationToken());
               });
           }
   ```
5. EDIT: CommandManager.GetList (from the linked pic above) calls:

```
    public async Task<CatsFileInfo[]> GetList(CancellationToken ct)
            {
                int timeoutInMilliseconds = 1000;
                IMessage[] messages = await _stateManager.ExecuteCommand(_catsFtpSerialConnection,
                    _messageFactory.BuildGetListMessage(), timeoutInMilliseconds, 0, ct);
                return _messageProcessor.ProcessMessagesForGetList(messages);
            }
```

Comment: "*I have never been so stumped in programming before*" That's awesome, you will have lots of fun and games in the years to come then. To answer this question though, lets look at the most obvious cause,  What is the implementation of `CommandManager.GetList` ? secondly, make sure you are in debug mode, and you have cleaned and rebuilt the application.

Comment: Async/await was supposed to simplify programming.  That only happens when the code works, when it doesn't then you have to be an expert.  You can't get anywhere until you find out where the exception got thrown.  Use Tools > Options > Debugging > General, untick "Just my code".  And to be sure, click Exception Settings > CLR Exceptions > tick System.FormatException so the debugger always stops.  Reproduce the crash.  If the debugger can't show you any source code then the Debug > Windows > Call Stack content is crucial, copy/paste it into your question.

Comment: @HansPassant I think your exception settings thing worked. The error started throwing from the place that it was happening (in another project in the solution) instead of from the running project. If I can verify that is right I guess I should answer my own question and mention you in it.

Comment: @HansPassant My question was how to debug it and you answered it perfectly. If you want to copy/paste it into an answer I’ll give it the ole green check mark as soon as I get the rep to.